React Tostify toast appearing twice
I have a React application with this code after a saving action:
import {toast} from 'react-toastify';
...
export const MyComponent = () => {
...
const updateData = async (data) => {
   toast('updating');
   const res = await httpClient.post('my-url', data);
   if (res.status === 200) { 
       toast('success');
   }
 }
...
}

The problem is that the second toast appears twice:

This is my React Toastify container:
  <ToastContainer
            containerId={'main-toast-container'}
            limit={1}
            position="top-center"
            hideProgressBar
        />

Additional info:

"react-router-dom": "^6.4.5"
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-toastify": "^9.1.2"
"vite": "^4.0.0"

What I've checked \ tried:

Put a toastId inside the options object
Move the toast container above the React router
Dismiss the toast (toas.dismiss(id))
Add auto close to both of them

